# How to create chaining of objects in js

Tags: javascript

I was asked in an interview to solve

`init(1).add(2).mul(3).div(4).val();`

Output it should achieve this functionality, I am more concerned about how to call in the above way

(1 + 2) * 3 / 4 = 2.25

How can we implement it using javascript? I thought of creating functions with nested function, whats the correct way?

I did

```
var gmap = function(num) {
this.x = num;

this.add = function(ad) {
    this.x = this.x * ad;
    return this;
}

this.del = function(de) {
   this.x = this.x + de;
   return this;
}

this.final = function() {
    return this.x;
}
```

}

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+fluent+interface  and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+method+chaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `class` style too

```js
class Chainable{

    init(num){
        this.total = num;
        return this;
    }

    add(num){
        this.total += num;
        return this;
    }
}
```

using it like so

```js
var c = new Chainable();
c.init(1).add(1);
```

Comment: Classes must be called with `new`.

Comment: Edited. careless on my part

Comment: As it's an interview question. Using class will probably be more appreciated

Comment: Why do we return this from the functions in the above solution?

Comment: `this` refers to the object that you just accessed. you can think of `this` as the variable `c` in this example. The key idea of chaining is to mutate the state (value) of that object and then return itself (so that you can chain).

Comment: @Abhishekgupta: You are doing the same in your solution. Don't you know why?

Comment: I know, but the interviewer wanted the way @SReject has done

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an instance of a class, you can make use of closures:

```js
function init(start) {
  // this is the starting value that will get updated with each function call
  let value = start;

  // This is the object to be returned, notice that seach return the object instance
  let self = {
      add: num => {
          value += num;
          return self;
      },
      sub: num => {
          value -= num;
          return self;
      },
      mul: num => {
          value *= num;
          return self;
      },
      div: num => {
          value /= num;
          return self;
      },
      val: () => {
          return value;
      }
  };

  return self;
}

init(1).add(2).mul(3).div(4).val(); // 2.25
```

Essentially, each time the init function is called a new closure-scope is created. Within this scope, new instances of any local variables that are created and only accessible within that scope.

When the init function is called, two new variable instances are created `value` and `self` that are only accessible to other 'things' created in the init function.

With each of those functions, we return the variable that contains the function-set which is how its able to chain calls.

Comment: This is what the interviewer wanted. (y)

Comment: Love the simple and straight-forward step-by-step explanation. That really helped with the understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using [builder pattern](https://github.com/fbeline/Design-Patterns-JS/blob/master/src/creational/builder/builder.js) ([ES6](https://github.com/fbeline/Design-Patterns-JS/blob/master/src/creational/builder/builder_es6.js)):

```
function init(value) {
    this.result = value;
    return {
        add: function(addValue) {
            this.result = this.result + addValue;
            return this;
        },
        mul: function(mulValue) {
            this.result = this.result * mulValue;
            return this;
        },
        div: function(divValue) {
            this.result = this.result / divValue
            return this;
        },
        val: function() {
            return this.result;
        },
        result: this.result,
    };

}

init(1).add(2).mul(3).div(4).result
```